# How does a view only wallet work and what is stored?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, blockchain, viewkey, cold-storage, view-only

In relation to blockchain scanning and disk usage, as well as disk space, how does a view only wallet work? Specifically:

1.)  does the blockchain need to be scanned?
2.)  how much free space is needed for storage?

If the view only wallet is offline for an extended period of time and then the GUI is launched again, will it reflect transactions from one month ago?  Presumably the wallet will scan from where it left off to look for any and all transactions on that wallet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does a view only wallet work

There are 2 sets of keys, view and spend. The private view key and public spend key are used for scanning the blockchain, to find outputs sent to you.

> and what is stored?

The wallet will store / record the outputs it see's are destined for that wallet. It also stores other things like the height last scanned to and of course the keys used.

> 1.) does the blockchain need to be scanned?

Yes, if you want to view incoming funds.

> 2.) how much free space is needed for storage?

The wallet (which is separate to the daemon), requires very little storage. What impacts storage is whether you're using a local daemon, pruned or unpruned, or a remote node. A pruned local node will require ~58G, and an unpruned local node about ~158G, as of this moment. Using a remote node has no storage requirement on the localhost.

> If the view only wallet is offline for an extended period of time and then the GUI is launched again, will it reflect transactions from one month ago? Presumably the wallet will scan from where it left off to look for any and all transactions on that wallet.

It will have to scan from where it last scanned to, if you have newer transactions since your last scan.